# TFS API: How do you get a local mapped path from a server path by using C#?

Tags: c#, tfs

I'm working with TFS API by C# and I have some trouble:

If I have the sever path, for instance `@"$/MyCompanyName/Services/MyFiles"` and I want to get appropriate mapped folder like `@"C:\MyCompanyName\Services\MyFiles"` by using C#?
For instance: I have source control path as constant that given from somewere, and I need to figure out the appropriate mapped path on local file system (if exists one).

Comment: You question is not clear, please rephrase it and write what exactly you are looking for. Also, what you have done till now.

Comment: It's easy to have multiple workspaces that may each map (parts of) TFS to a single machine (as well as other workspaces that are applicable on other machines). So, how do you want to deal with that?

Comment: I've improved the question, and I have also answered by myself.

Comment: Could you guys please undo your negative votes? Due to the facts I improved my question, it has viewed more than 1000 times and my solution has 4 positive votes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer by myself:

1). First, needs to find the Workspace instance:

```
 var workspaceInfo = Workstation.Current.GetLocalWorkspaceInfo(@"$/MyFolder1/MyFolder2/MyFolder3");

                if (workspaceInfo != null) //is already exists
                {
                    var server = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(workspaceInfo.ServerUri);
                    workspace = workspaceInfo.GetWorkspace(server);
                }
```

2). Second step is calculation of mapped folder:

```
 string workspaceFolderFullPath = workspace?.GetLocalItemForServerItem((@"$/MyFolder1/MyFolder2/MyFolder3");
```

Answer (score 0):

After you have connected to the team project, you can manage your workspaces from the Team Explorer home page or from Source Control Explorer.

[image]

[image]

After you choose Add or Edit you can modify working folders in a new or an existing workspace.

[image]

More information, check: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/create-work-workspaces

Comment: Thanks, but I wrote in title of question "by using C#", means by code and not through GUI.